# Disable green download notification progress bar from Mozilla Firefox taskbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, firefox

I have searched and also check the setting into Mozilla Firefox about: config for  hiding the green color downloading progress bar showing  the taskbar please the screenshot:

[image]

Is there any solutions I don't want to show this [green](http://prntscr.com/flx0ko) color progress bar which is indicated about something downloading

I have also try to hide it on Google Chrome but same not luck any help will be appreciated   Mozilla Firefox version 53.0.3 (32-bit)

Comment: You mean so the user does not know you are downloading malware on his computer?

Comment: Yes absolutely, it's not about other users computers I am wanted it on my computer only and I want to know for the knowledge purpuse.

Comment: You very rarely have access to any of the browser's "chrome" - meaning the  ui - from a very good security reason.-

Comment: can I know why this question going for down vote, Is it wrong to ask the question, just for the sake of knowledge?I was just curious

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I'd assume it's because you've shown no research effort, nor any code you've written in an attempt to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. That behaviour is controlled by the integration between the browser and the operating system at a much lower level than JS has access to.

Comment: Thanks for reply @RM I know but there may be something possible? its large communication website so  I have asked there we know that we have not accessed to Firefox libraries etc

Comment: Sorry, it's an OS feature controlled by the browser. It's also a security feature as @mplungjan pointed out, as it allows users to know when files are being downloaded on their machines. It cannot be avoided - and any attempts to do so would be very suspicious.